Print List based on conditions
How do I print only the values of p which are all True?
In addition, is this an efficient use of a Loop in this situation or can this be improved without using a lietral for loop?
For[i = 10200, i <= 10500, i++, v = Divisors[i];
 p = PrimeQ[v + (i/v)]; Print[i]; Print[p]]

Thanks.

Clear["Global`*"];
test[i_] := AllTrue[Divisors[i], PrimeQ[# + (i/#)] &];
Select[Range[10200, 10500], test]

(* {10222, 10390, 10462} *)

